# How do I Distribute my Haxe application with Hashlink?

Tags: haxe, hashlink

I've got a Haxe Application that I want to make available to people with a Windows system. I use Hashlink to run the Application locally and it works very nicely.

I am wondering if I'm supposed to distribute my Application with Hashlink. Can it build me an .exe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like generating distributable binary files isn't supported out of the box today (March 10, 2017):

```
> haxe -main Main -hl main.c
Code generated in main.c automatic native compilation not yet implemented
```

Hopefully it will be supported soon!

***Note:*** I'm talking about building a final executable using hashlink. An entirely separate approach I do not cover here is the possibility of delivering the hashlink virtual machine with your output hl bitcode.

***Sane people stop reading here.***

But in the meantime... it is *possible* to generate binaries with hashlink today if you build hashlink from source.

**Warnings:**

- This isn't a generic, cross-platform answer to your question -- it's just my experience on Linux.
- There will probably soon be a better way than this.
- But I wanted to jot these notes down even for myself to recall later.

Here's what I had to do on Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit:

Install prerequisite libraries for building hl (there may be others I already have installed, like build-essential, etc)

```
sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev libturbojpeg libsdl2-dev libopenal-dev libssl-dev
```

Clone and build the mbedtls library: (rev note: `b5ba28`)

```
cd ~/dev/
git clone https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git
cd mbedtls
make CFLAGS='-fPIC'
```

Clone the hashlink repo: (rev note: `eaa92b`)

```
cd ~/dev/
git clone https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hashlink.git
cd hashlink
```

In the `# Linux` section of the `Makefile`, ~line 67, add these flags:

```
CFLAGS += -I ../mbedtls/include
LIBFLAGS += -L../mbedtls/library
```

Now build with `make`

If everything works, you'll see two important output files, `hl` and `libhl.so`

Ok, at this point, it's easiest if you just build your project in the hashlink directory. For example:

```
# Still in the hashlink directory
haxe -cp /path/to/my/project -debug -main Main.hx -hl src/_main.c
```

Now run `make hlc`, and if everything works, `hlc` is the output executable (which depends on `libhl.so`):

```
cp libhl.so hlc /tmp/
cd /tmp/
./hlc
```

Prints:

```
Main.hx:7: Hello world!
```